# Way to extract all parts of GMail message

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I can obtain a message from GMail like this

```
Dim GMailMessage As Message = myGMailService.Users.Messages.Get(ProfileUsager.GoogleAccountUserName, ID).Execute
```

But I must extract attachments, from, to CC, subject, received date, etc. from this message. How I can do this. I try to get Raw format and full format but with no success I can easily extract all data from this message.

Do you have a sample of code or something that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a mail parser as there are many about.

I use Mailbee

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/email-components

Parse the Gmail Message to their object and then access the properties.

```
 gr.Format = UsersResource.MessagesResource.GetRequest.FormatEnum.Raw;
 Message m = new Message();
 m = gr.Execute();

 byte[] decodedByte = FromBase64ForUrlString(m.Raw);
 string base64Encoded = Convert.ToString(decodedByte);

 currentMessage = new MailMessage();
 currentMessage.LoadMessage(decodedByte);

 Response.Write(currentMessage.From.DisplayName);
```

You could parse the message yourself but it is quite complex and why re-invent the wheel.

**Edit in response to question**

```
    public static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: What is FromBase64ForUrlString ?